# ExceptionList Class - VB

Tags: exception, list

I need to return an exception that contains a list of exceptions. This is easy enough to do, but I'd like to know if there is a built-in Exception Class that does this as I'd hate to "roll my own" instead of following built-in, documented classes.

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Returning exceptions is something of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "throw exception".

Comment: I agree, exceptions should always be thrown (unless it's an Exceptoin Factory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the *[InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_members.aspx)* property, but if you need more than that, you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks - it is theoretically possible to create a linked list of Exceptions, using the InnerException property, but the purpose of the InnerException is to give a reference to the Exception that caused that Exception (that contains the property). So, I think it would be a mis-use of the property to use it for Exceptions that are basically orthogonal, so I will (and have) gone ahead with my own ExceptionList class.